# How can I use a variable in a path? (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use a variable to acsess the array... how?

example:
(HTML FILE // VAR variable_here)

```
<div class="subject-box" ng-repeat="subj in tmc.schultage.variable_here">
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Calvin

Comment: did you try brackets notation ?

Comment: We really can't help without see what do you have in your `tmc.schultage.variable_here`.

Comment: can you be clear/descriptive with your question

Comment: Please show your array first..

Comment: check it http://jsfiddle.net/mkq7q4so/

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. Is it the URL, where you want to pass the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Square brackets to pass value as an object key.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div class="subject-box" ng-repeat="subj in tmc.schultage[name]">
  {{subj}}
  </div>
</div>




var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'someArray';
    $scope.tmc = {
        schultage : {
        someArray : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
      }
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mkq7q4so/)